# autocompletebox focus in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

when I try to focus on my "autocompletetextbox" I failed I write `autocompletetextbox.focus()`
but the cursor still focus in another what should I do or write to enable to write in it or focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I experienced the same thing -- it does not work properly in its current form (I expect you're talking about the AutoCompleteBox that comes with the February 2010 release of WPFToolkit).

I created a subclass:

```
public class AutoCompleteFocusableBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var textbox = Template.FindName("Text", this) as TextBox;
        if(textbox != null) textbox.Focus();
    }
}
```

This sets focus to the actual `TextBox` (called "Text") that is part of the default `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: where should I put this class I tried at the class which has the auto complete box but it doesn't work ?

Comment: In your XAML you use this instead of `AutoCompleteBox`. So if you have this class in namespace XYZ, you import that namespace in the root of the XAML file, with an alias like xyz and then use <xyz:AutoCompleteFocusableBox Width="500" x:Name="myFocusBox" …>

Comment: I tried but blend get me an error AutoCompleteFocusableBox doesn't support wpf!!!

Comment: Are you in fact using the February 2010 WPFToolkit release? What version of Blend? This works for me in Blend 3. With your project loaded in blend, you should be able to find this control using the search feature in the toolbox, and add it through the GUI just like any other control.

Comment: @Jay What setup for the class should be used? I just have a .cs file called BetterACBox and I have imported the namespace in my xaml window but I get the following error when adding the control in: `the specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. the following type was expected uielement`

Comment: @mbdavis Make sure you are inheriting from the toolkit `AutoCompleteBox` as in my example above.

Comment: I have been, I have the following code in a file called 'BetterACBox.cs': `public class BetterACBox : AutoCompleteBox
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            var textbox = Template.FindName("Text", this) as TextBox;
            if (textbox != null) textbox.Focus();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 5):

You will have to override the Focus method to find the template of the Textbox.

```
public class FocusableAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    public new void Focus()
    {
        var textbox = Template.FindName("Text", this) as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null) textbox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: `using System.Windows.Controls;` too

Comment: and how to call this inside a method?

Answer (score 5):

This is very old question, but I want to share my work-around.

```
Keyboard.Focus(autocompletetextbox);
autocompletetextbox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

This works in `WPFToolkit v3.5.50211.1` on `Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have to wait for the auto complete box to load first. Then set focus

```xml
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox 
   x:Name="_employeesAutoCompleteBox" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   ValueMemberPath="DisplayName" >    
</sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

```cs
_employeesAutoCompleteBox.Loaded +=
    (sender, e) => ((AutoCompleteBox)sender).Focus();
```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me today. nothing else. well done!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution,

> I found it easier than having inherited class

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = FindVisualChild<TextBox>(CodedCommentBox);
    textBox.Focus();
}

private TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(DependencyObject obj) where TChildItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

        var item = child as TChildItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            return item;
        }

        var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(child);
        if (childOfChild != null)
        {
            return childOfChild;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for setting focus on AutoCompleteTextBox control Text:

private void MyPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
var myPage = (MyControl)sender;
var autoTextBox = (AutoCompleteTextBox)myPage.FindName("AutoTextBox");

if (autoTextBox != null)
{
    var innerTextBox = autoTextBox.textBox;
    if (innerTextBox != null)
    {
        innerTextBox.Focus();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a extension method for this:

```cs
public static void ForceFocus(this AutoCompleteBox box)
{
    if (box.Template.FindName("Text", box) is TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.Focus();
    }
}
```