# How to focus into AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to focus into AutoCompleteBox? I've tried many of code by searching on stackover but not getting focus. here is some code which i wrote.

```
        <controls:AutoCompleteBox Name="SearchTextBox" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" PreviewKeyDown="SearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"  >
            <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

and for focus i've creating a class named FocusableAutoCompleteBox

```
public class FocusableAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
    {
        public new void Focus()
        {
            var textbox = Template.FindName("SearchTextBox", this) as AutoCompleteBox;
            if (textbox != null) textbox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

and focus by

```
new FocusableAutoCompleteBox().Focus();
```

but errors appears

> Object Reference not set to an instance of object

I also tried `SearchTextBox.Focus();` but not getting result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autocompletebox focus in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572299/autocompletebox-focus-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
Keyboard.Focus(SearchTextBox);
                SearchTextBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```